# Custom action filter in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

You are developing an ASP.NET MVC application.
Before an action is executed, information about the action must be written to a log. After
results are returned, information about the results also must be written to the log.
You need to log the actions and results.
You have the following code:

```
**Target 1**
{
public override void **Target 2**
{
  Logger.Log("ActionLog", filterContext.RouteData);
}
public override void **Target 3**
{
  Logger.Log("ResultLog", filterContext.RouteData);
}
}
```

Which code segments should you include in **Target 1**, **Target 2** and **Target 3** to implement the LogActionFilter class? (To answer, select the appropriate option from the list)

```
Option 1) public class LogActionFilter : IActionFilter
Option 2) public class LogActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
Option 3) OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
Option 4) OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
Option 5) OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
Option 6) OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
```

From blog and other sources, I found 2 type of answers. Some chose Option 2, Option 3 and Option 5 respectively. If this is the case, then my question is why not Option 6 instead of Option 5.

Please help me. I appreciate your valuable response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Relating to this [link](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/hands-on-labs/aspnet-mvc-4-custom-action-filters)

**Target 1: Option 2) public class LogActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute**

Because **ActionFilterAttribute** is the base class for all the attribute filters.This class implements both the IActionFilter and IResultFilter interfaces and inherits from the Filter class. It provides the following methods to execute a specific logic after and before controller action's execution:

1- **OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutedContext filterContext):** Just before the action method is called.

2- **OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutingContext filterContext):** After the action method is called and before the result is executed (before view render).

3-  **OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext):** Just before the result is executed (before view render).

4- **OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext):** After the result is executed (after the view is rendered).

So,accordingly from the description of the methods above:

**Target 2: Option 3) OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)**

**Target 3: Option 6) OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)**